# Android - Firebase push notification backend showing error

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have not more experience of Android and almost have no idea in javascript coding, I followed a tutorial to create a firebase function and now **firebase function change beta to stable** and my code is showing me error :

**this is my code --->**

```js
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context)=> {

  const user_id = context.params.user_id;
  const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

  console.log('We have a notification from : ', user_id);

  if (!event.data.exists()) {

    return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);

  }

  const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');

  return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {

    const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;

    console.log('You have new notification from  : ', from_user_id);
 
    const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`Users/${from_user_id}/name`).once('value');
    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

    return Promise.all([userQuery, deviceToken]).then(result => {

      const userName = result[0].val();
      const token_id = result[1].val();
        
      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title : "New Friend Request",
          body: `${userName} has sent you request`,
          icon: "default",
          click_action : "in.tvac.akshaye.lapitchat_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
        },
        data : {
          from_user_id : from_user_id
        }
      };

      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

        console.log('This was the notification Feature');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

**and this is my database ---->**

- notifications
- BOhvOUJG8sWgIyTD7JLuSOgfv9v1

  - aqTdCWJYfvQiw188MqldsDtlLFf2
    -LLO14ghpMruZtqwK7CR from:  "rrajSiL7SFd7WQydkA7jwxi26s63" type:  "request"
    -LLOQ2WsWHymJvdOxrx5 from:  "rrajSiL7SFd7WQydkA7jwxi26s63" type:  "request"
    -LLfVM43o8Rt-1A55r28
    -LLfxudlktvk3ysxvype

**i am getting this error --->**

```
ReferenceError: event is not defined
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:15:7)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:733:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved now, it is just because of firebase function migrated beta to stable and some syntax had changed, If anyone got same error, u can get a solution from the below link -
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please check if you have defined the event or not

Comment: Thank you so much, but now my problem solved it just because of firebase function changed beta to stable and some syntax have changed,

Comment: If anyone got same error u can get solution from this link --->https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff